# Comma or colon after a word like "Remember" followed by a sentence addressed directly to reader?

Tags: commas, colons, imperatives

In these sentences:

> Take the time to buckle your seatbelt. Remember, it's better to be
>   safe than sorry.

Should `Remember` be followed by a comma or a colon?

Comment: Neither is needed. You can say *remember (that) it's better to be safe than sorry* just as you can say *I think (that) punctuation is unnecessary here.*

Comment: Of course it's not necessary, but these kinds of constructions are used for dramatic effect. Directly addressing the reader grabs his/her attention.

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely stylistic.[1] You are essentially issuing an order in the imperative ("Remember") and the entire clause "it's better to be safe than sorry" is the object of that command.

Although no punctuation is valid, I think in this case at least a comma is called for. It separates the imperative clause from the object clause, and makes it an easier sentence to read since the comma flags the clause separation, especially here where the second clause is an independent clause (a sentence by itself).

Most English speakers wouldn't bat an eye at a colon either.  It makes for a more dramatic pause, in my mind that makes it come across as if it were being read in a TV announcer voice. The grammatical justification would be that both sides of the colon are essentially equivalent,[2] although you sort of have to imply a "this" after the "Remember".

[1] Nice collection of descriptions of when a comma is appropriate here: [Do you separate an imperative after a conjunction by a comma?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171275/do-you-separate-an-imperative-after-a-conjunction-by-a-comma)

[2] http://academics.smcvt.edu/writingctr/semicolons.htm ("Use a colon between two complete sentences if the second summarizes the first")

Comment: "Although no punctuation is valid,..." -- I think you might want to word that differently.